# Ссылка на таблицу по имени

Tags: lua

В некотором месте кода я пирисваиваю своей переменной ссылку на таблицу (т. е. её идентичность):

```
local defines = ffi.lcpp_defs
```

Однако, библиотека каждый раз создаёт новую таблицу с тем же именем. В свою очередь, локальная `defines`, всё ещё ссылается на старую таблицу (идентичность). Как же сделать ссылку на имя таблицы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В lua для этого можно использовать т. н. "прокси-таблицу", пробросить все (нужные) методы таблицы при помощи метаметодов. К примеру:

```
local defines = setmetatable({}, {
__index = function(s, i)
    return ffi.lcpp_def[i]
end})
```

В этом примере мы можем только считывать данные из таблицы.

P. S.: данный приём также применяется при необходимости ограниченого доступа к таблице (в сочетании с upvalue).

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать метаметоды __newindex и __index:

```
-- Проксификатор
function proxytable(table,key)
  return setmetatable({},{
    __index=function(self,k) return table[key][k] end,
    __newindex=function(self,k,v) table[key][k] = v end,
  })
end
local defines = proxytable(ffi,"lcpp_defs")
```

В этом примере можно и считывать, и записывать в таблицу, на которую ссылается прокси-таблица